# how to test data behaviour in Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rest

I am trying to build a costing CRUD-app for a friend. I would like to use the API only mode of rails to serve `json` to a front-end. There are only 6 tables, two are one_to_one.

I have built an app before with ruby and sinatra with a postgresql database. I am familiar enough with ruby to tackle rails.

I have got my tables up, relations set (i think). I can seed tables one at a time data but because of dependencies, some tables will not populate if I try to seed everything at once.

I have created join tables for the `one_to_many` and `many_to_many`relations.

What I am not sure about is how to proceed. I am not sure how to test everything. How do I know my models are working? It's the associations I feel are mostly important to test, otherwise, how will I know I am ready to move on?

My questions are:

*Does rails take care of all referencing of foreign ids and such, or is one required to enter these manually, if so where and under which situations?

*Why can't I seed all the tables at once with seeds.rb file? Is it because of 'constraints' on reference tables? Can I not use a seeded db to test associations in the console?

*Which is the best testing framework to test model associations? Is there a good guide out this kind of testing?

*Once the model associations are tested, am I then ready to adjust the controllers to serve `json` and test it with a REST client? Would I be done then?

I would be grateful for any answers to these questions.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should ask one specific question, preferably with some code. That way you'll get better response.

Comment: fair enough. I will ask with some code, specific questions.